# Transloadit - is there a way to ignore artwork when encoding mp3s?

Tags: ffmpeg, transloadit

Is there a way to exclude artwork with [Transloadit's /audio/encode robot](https://transloadit.com/docs/transcoding/#audio-encode)?

I’m using the /audio/encode robot to convert audio to a constant bitrate of 96kbps. My assembly step looks like this:

```
"encode_mp3": {
  "use": "concat",
  "robot": "/audio/encode",
  "preset": "mp3",
  "bitrate": 96,
  "ffmpeg_stack": "v4.3.1"
}
```

This has been working reliably for over 100 files, but for one particular file it’s failing with this error:

```
AudioArtworkTool failed with exit code: 1. There was a problem inserting audio artwork for file 76as32df876.
```

TBH I don’t actually want artwork embedded in my files - I don’t need it and I’d prefer to save the bandwidth and avoid any of these errors in the future. Is there a way to exclude artwork with the /audio/encode robot? Perhaps some ffmpeg magic I could feed into the ffmpeg field? If not, how would I go about debugging artwork-related errors?

Comment: Adding the ffmpeg parameter `-vn` will result in the artwork being ignored. But not sure what the API syntax is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim here, Co-founder of Transloadit. This should be fixing it for you:

> ...
>
> "bitrate": 96,
>
> "ffmpeg_stack": "v4.3.1",
>
> "ffmpeg": {
>
> "vn": true,
>
> "vsync": 0
>
> }

That should do the trick for you. :)